# How can I make Google Chrome shortcut in windows 8 actually open in a browser rather than a restricted viewer

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

In Windows 8 I can create a shortcut to a webpage and save it on the desktop.

When I click on this it opens the link in a restricted viewer that removes all the useful browser functionality, such as the back button, meaning I can't properly navigate from the link.

How do I make shortcuts to webpages open in a normal browser, or better still, in a new tab (assuming the browser is open)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: using Windows.

Right click anywhere on the Desktop, select **New**, **Shortcut**.

Now, type (paste) the full URL, like `http://www.google.com`. Click **Next**. Give it a name that will be shown and click **Next** again. That's it. It will now open in the default browser.

If you made the shortcut from the Chrome Apps screen, delete the Desktop shortcut, go to the Apps screen again, right-click the app you want shortcut for and select the first option: **Open in normal tab** (or something like). Now make the shortcut again, by right-clicking that app again and select the shortcut option.

If you want the shortcut in the start menu press <kbd>Win+R</kbd> and type:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

Now, copy the previously created shortcut there ([source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/add-a-shortcut-to-win-8-start-screen/3727e08e-6dec-45d9-aed8-b746f152ff7b)). Launch Start and look for your shortcut in all items. You can now right-click and pin it to Start.

Comment: works, so plus one and accept for answering my question, however, on right click of the resulting short-cut I can't pin it to Windows start menu, which was actually my ultimate goal, the option 'pin to start' is not available! do you know why?

Comment: @ToniLeigh see the edit.